# Gravitational field at a point $P$ in a small hole dug in a thin spherical shell?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, linear-systems

I am supposed to find the field at a point $P$ in a hole, I initially thought that since the field inside is $0$ initally, now it must be $GM/R^2$ but that is not so, since we cannot assume it to behave a like a point object now, to find the field, one way is to calculate field due to all infinitesimal small parts of the shell, but that seems a bit too complicated. Any help is appreciated.